# Create a powerful Creature

Tags: creature

Im working on a short trailer that involves a big dragon.

I've been thinking alot about how to capture this big massive beast and i'm completely out of ideas... For the footsteps i've put together some sub elements, rocks shaking, something cracking and many more... But there's something missing... I want to capture the movement of this beast... What should i do? I've tried pitching down and time stretched some whip/whoop sounds but doesn't seem to work...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can check out how David Farmer did the sound for the Fellbeast's in LoTR they used a bunch of cheese grader swooshes for the tail. (skip to 1min 20sec):

[youtube]RMNwotOm27g[/youtube]

[youtube]KwFs5Pr2IZc[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head; since Dragons are supposed to have a sort of "Scale" to their skin... you might want to take some leather swatches of various states of soft/hardness and twist them in time with the dragons movements to create a sort of creaking skin/scale sound.

A piece of leather that's wet and left out to dry will have a bit more squeaky resonance than a softer piece of leather. You can usually buy a whole side of leather from a local shop and then treat it to different forms of soaking, different soaking materials (Oil vs Water or Oil and Water ratios vs various drying times or drying conditions).

Record those sounds at 192/24 and that way you can pitch them down and get some depth to it, especially when layering.

You might also want to record some "sliding" sounds across different types of surfaces to layer on the "creaks". ie: slide a book across a table and maybe apply a filter/EQ sweep to it to give it some motion, then when it's in your mix, pan appropriately.

Ok, good luck... let us know what you ended up doing and how you did it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try focusing on the movement of the tail rather than the footsteps.  Dragons (if they existed) would be very light on their feet just like elephants and other large creatures.  You can convey the weight and power by having a large low swishing sound as it moves, try attaching a large bucket or something similar to a stick and moving it fast past the mic, remember to tape down the handle so it doesn't rattle.  You could then layer it with a moving leather jacket, you can create lots of sounds by scrumpling it, passing it through air, and stretching it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make some whooshes for the wings and tail (panned according to the picture) with some leather, plus you could try stretching some hard leather piece to add in those movements cause they could add some realism to the dragon skin movement (except your dragon has metal parts and stuff so tha means you can add lots of different things), then do some time stretch on those elements and EQ to make the "big", you could also try some lion roar time stretched down to add to the actual dragon characterization (exscuse my bad english here...), and if your dragon breaths some fire then thats a whole different story and there are many things you can do...

You can watch the interview from the sound maker of the upcoming Elder Scrolls Skyrim. I found those videos on GameInformer.com site some time ago and the guy explained how he did the sound from the dragons in that game, i found it very helpfull so i suggest you watch these videos too SS.

please post some of your work when you get it done cause it is really interesting :) cheers!